# Rails - Model Namespace And Folder Structure For Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, namespaces, directory

I'm trying to understand what's the proper way to setup model folders.  I'm running into some name resolution conflicts.

I have a rails model (transport) that corresponds to a db table.  Import and export are types of transports and inherent from the transport class.  There are also middle classes that define code common to that level of hierarchy.

Here's how it's currently setup:

```
models/  
models/transport.rb  
models/transport/  
models/transport/import.rb  
models/transport/import/  
models/transport/import/api.rb  
models/transport/import/api/  
models/transport/import/api/metric.rb  
models/transport/import/api/order.rb  
models/transport/import/csv.rb  
models/transport/import/csv/  
models/transport/import/csv/metric.rb  
models/transport/import/csv/order.rb  
models/transport/export/  
models/transport/export/api.rb  
...
```

Here are some class snippets:

```
models/transport.rb
class Transport < ActiveRecord::Base
  # common transport code
end

models/transport/import.rb    
class Transport  
  class Import < Transport  
    # common import code  
  end  
end  

models/transport/import/api.rb
class Transport
  class Import
    class Api < Transport::Import
      # common api code
    end
  end
end

models/transport/import/api/metric.rb
class Transport
  class Import
    class Api
      class Metric < Transport::Import::Api
        # metric code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Question:  What's the proper way to organize rails model folders/namespaces?

Specifically when you are inheriting functionality rather than extending functionality through an inner namespace.

The current code has errors because ruby thinks it's inheriting it's outer class.  I thought about using a base folder to avoid contention, but wanted to understand what others would do in a similar situation.

```
models/  
models/base/    
models/base/transport.rb  
models/transport/  
models/transport/import.rb  
models/transport/import/  
models/transport/import/api.rb
```

Comment: for namespace i use `module` not `class`. `rails/ruby` understands it well and this very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what [Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) stated I think all of the Transport classes should be namespaced as a module.

So it'd look something like the following (not not my recommendation):

```
# models/transport.rb
module Transport
  # common transport code
end

# models/transport/import.rb    
module Transport  
  module Import 
    # common import code  
  end  
end  

# models/transport/import/api.rb
module Transport
  module Import
    module Api
      # common api code
    end
  end
end

# models/transport/import/api/metric.rb
module Transport
  module Import
    module Api
      class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base
        # metric code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't recommend putting classes inside classes.  That gets confusing. It really seems like you have a transport model that can be an import or an export.  I'm not sure what the difference is between them other than one may send and one may receive.  If that's all I'd not make the folder structure so complex.

Maybe just have something like:

```
# models/transport.rb
module Transport
  # Stuff that import and export both need, that isn't instance specific
end

# models/transport/import.rb    
module Transport  
  class Import < ActiveRecord::Base
    # common import code  
  end  
end  

# models/transport/export.rb    
module Transport  
  class Export < ActiveRecord::Base
    # common export code  
  end  
end
```

To help give a better answer I think we need to better understand what API and Metric are and how they play into import and export.